# Android - dialog stretches over the screen height

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I have a function that creates a dialog which has a title, some text and an EditText at the bottom.
It also has 2 buttons at the bottom.
However when the text is too long the dialog height increases until the buttons are barely reachable, although a scrollbar for the large text does appear and not the entire text is shown.

Here are images of the dialog before and after a lot of text appears in the body...
[image: The dialog at first]

[image: the dialog after a lot of text]

Here is how I spawn the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainProgram.currentActivity);
dialogbuilder.setTitle("Title:");
final EditText input = new EditText(MainProgram.currentActivity);
dialogbuilder.setView(input);

dialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    }
});

dialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    }
});

dialogbuilder.create().show();
```

How can I fix this problem (programmatically) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input.setMaxLines` to set a maximum number of lines. You must type this line before setting `input` as view. Hope this help you!

Comment: @VladimirGazbarov if this answer helps you, please check it as the good one. Thanks

Comment: What you proposed did limit the number of lines in the editText object. The problem is that the dialog's message stretches it...